# Neighborhood of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have two conceptual questions I'd like some clarification on.

1. Suppose we have a complex function and its partial derivatives are continuous and the Cauchy Remain equations are satisfied iff x=y. Is this function considered Analytic? How can we define its neighborhood? Should the neighborhood be 2 dimensional (not a line) thus implying not analytical?
2. Suppose we have a complex function and its partial derivatives are not continuous at x=0 (suppose it makes the denominator zero), but the Cauchy Reiman equations are satisfied everywhere. Is this function considered analytic?

Comment: In this setting, neighborhood are open sets  in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$. For (1) yes, if a function $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood $W$ of a point $z_0$ and the partial derivatives satisfy the R-C equations, then $f$ is analytic in $W$.

Comment: Conversely, if a function is analytic in a neighborhood $W$ of $z_0$, then $f$ is differentiable in $W$ (in the sense of $\mathbb{R}^2$) and the Cauchy equations hold. This can bee seen in Rudin's book of Real-Complex analysis for example.